# JPA with OSGi DS example

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, declarative-services

I am trying to figure out an example of `JPA`*(containing an example of Student Entity, with name and class)* using `Eclipselink & Derby`. I am able to do it in Java EE but I can't figure out a way to do it simply in `OSGi` using `Declarative Services`.

Can anyone share some info on any such examples which uses `JPA with OSGi DS`?

Some of the examples I have gone through are [here](https://github.com/dpishchukhin/org.knowhowlab.tips.jpa), but these examples use `getReference` or `getTracker` however I don't want to use them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at the OSGi enRoute project's tutorial. This is still work in progress but in phase 10 it actually uses JPA, transactions, etc.

https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.blog

In the master branch there is a PDF that describes the tutorial in detail, step by step. Each step is a branch so you can look at the 10-jpa branch. It uses bndtools.

This is work in progress but it should give you a good idea.

Comment: according to the repo this example is now deprecated (the osgi.enroute.blog). is there a new version or some information how to get JPA to work for tests and release?

Comment: +1 for Gadi's comment. It would be extremely helpful to have a current and minimalist example of how to use JPA with osgi enRoute.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the osgi.enroute.blog project mentioned by Peter; additionally I hope you might find my [blog post](http://skysailserver.blogspot.de/2013/11/using-flyway-with-osgi-part-one.html) about using flyway and OSGi useful. If you ignore the flyway parts, you will find an example project using eclipselink and osgi declarative services.